# How do I Sort, Slice, then Map an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, slice

Im trying to sort, then **slice (show last n elements of array only)** and then map this array.

This is the working version (react syntax) currently, with sort and map but without slicing yet.

```
{Object.keys(dataObj)
                      .sort(
                        (a, b) =>
                          dataObj[a]["order"] -
                          dataObj[b]["order"]
                      )
                      .map((movie, i) => {
                        return (
                          <li key={i}>
                            {movie}
                            {dataObj[movie]["value"]}
                          </li>
                        );
                      })}
```

How do I continue to slice this, in between sort and map?
This is what my pseudo code would look like.

```
{Object.keys(dataObj)
                      .sort(
                        (a, b) =>
                          dataObj[a]["order"] -
                          dataObj[b]["order"]
                      )
                      .((arr)=>arr.slice(arr.length-10, arr.length+1))
                      .map((movie, i) => {
                        return (
                          <li key={i}>
                            {movie}
                            {dataObj[movie]["value"]}
                          </li>
                        );
                      })}
```

This obviously does not work but how do I carry on to **Slice** after the **.sort** which returns an array?
And then map this sliced array afterwards.
What syntax do I use? Thanks!

Comment: you could just filter it based on the index. `arr.sort(sortFn).filter( (item, idx) => idx > arr.length - 10).map(mapFn)`

Answer (score 4):

You could take [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  directly with a negative index from the end.

```
Object.keys(dataObj)
    .sort((a, b) => dataObj[a].order - dataObj[b].order)
    .slice(-10)
    .map((movie, i) => {
        return (
            <li key={i}>
               {movie} {dataObj[movie].value }
            </li>
        );
    })
```

Comment: Wow thats a quick fix. Thanks!!